# PyQt load module during QSplashScreen

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-import, splash-screen

I have a simpl PyQt5 application that loads a module, which is required for a Worker class that performs a calculation: this load is slow (it's a big module) and so I would like to do it while the splash screen is displayed. However, I can't seem to figure out how to load it late but into global namespace, or at least in such a way that it is available to the Worker class.

Here is the outline of my application:

```
import largeSlowLoadingModule

class Worker:

    def __init__():
        largeSlowLoadingModule.calculate()

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    pixmap = QPixmap("splash.png")
    splash = QSplashScreen(pixmap)
    
    # show the splash screen first...
    splash.show()

    # application continues here...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Is that module only used inside the worker?

Comment: Essentially, yes. There is another reference in another class but this could be removed.

Comment: Then import it only in the init of the module (or in the function in which you use it, since I suppose you're using a thread).